# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS in netty

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

I am modifying elasticsearch code to configure HTTPS without x-pack and reverse proxies.
I modified initchannel() method in the netty4HttpServerTransport file , https is working fine,but i want to redirect http to https..
The code is,

```
char[] password = "your5663".toCharArray();
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/keystore1.jks"),password);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, password);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext  = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
        sslContext .init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);
        SSLEngine sslengine = sslContext .createSSLEngine();

        sslengine.setUseClientMode(false);

        String[] DEFAULT_PROTOCOLS = { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2","TLSv1.3" };
        String[] DEFAULT_CIPHERS = {"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"};

        sslengine.setEnabledProtocols(DEFAULT_PROTOCOLS);
        sslengine.setEnabledCipherSuites(DEFAULT_CIPHERS);

        SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslengine);
        ch.pipeline().addLast("ssl", sslHandler);      
        ch.pipeline().addAfter("ssl","handshake",new StringEventHandler());
```

How do i make http to https redirect in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect works on the payload (http) level, not ssl transport level. You would need to listen on both protocol (http and https) and on the http channel you can respond with redirect status code.  Long story short - there is no direct place on in your code you can do that.

Very commonly a proxy server is used for this task. I am not sure if you can do it in elasticsearch, you can try to configure a filter servlet to check the protocol respond with a redirect. This may be helpful https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-transport-wares

Another fact  - if the redirect is for service clients (not browser based ui), the clients may/will consider a redirect response an an error response. Depending on your environment - maybe you can just expose the ssl endpoint (no redirects) and clients will have to comply

Answer (score 0):

Netty has a built in handler for this, [OptionalSslHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/OptionalSslHandler.java).

You put it at the front of your pipeline and it detects if the message is encrypted or not. If it is, then the message will be sent onto the normal SSL pipeline, if not then you can specify somewhere else to send it, e.g. to a 301 redirect to https.

You could either use this Netty version or make your own handler that does something similar.

However, to use the Netty version you will need to refactor slightly to produce a **Netty** SslContext `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext`, instead of an SSLEngine.

Something like this:

```
char[] password = "your5663".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("C:/OpenSSL-Win64/bin/keystore1.jks"),password);

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, password);

SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyManagerFactory).build();

ch.pipeline().addLast("ssl", sslHandler);

// this is an imaginary handler you create that sends HTTP a 301 to HTTPS
// non-SSL can be detected easily because there is no SslHandler on this channel
ch.pipeline().addLast("redirectHandler", new RedirectHandler()); 

ch.pipeline().addLast("handshake",new StringEventHandler());
```